# Why is `@eval` added in front of `using Package` in Julia?

Tags: macros, julia, eval

I've seen this construction several times, for example for [automatically loading Revise](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/config/#Using-Revise-by-default-1):

```
try
    @eval using Revise
catch
```

Why is the `@eval` macro needed here? What happens if we leave it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's needed if you want to use `using` in function scope.
`using` always needs to be executed in global scope, and eval works around that, since eval is always executed in global scope (that's also why you can't use eval to create local variables).

> What happens if we leave it out?

Why don't you try it?

Comment: I see, and in the example of Revise it is inside a function scope because of the `do`-block. As for testing, I didn't quite know how to test it but with your explanation I tried `foo() = begin using Revise end` and I could see the difference with  `foo() = begin @eval using Revise end`.